# Codename one Send IOS app store build

Tags: codenameone

I have Apple ID. When I am trying to Send IOS app store build in MAC system, I am getting Build Error.

I have created certificates for this, might be this step leads to error{ created certificate with device UDID}.

Please help me on how to create certificates and send IOS store build.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the error log contain? Did you use the certificate wizard? Are both certificates defined (debug/productions)? Which IDE did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly this all features directly by using netbean. There is wizard "Generate" for ios from which you can create development certificate as well as provision profile. You can also add devices by using the wizard in ios tab.